# Angular 2 change @ViewChildren after new entry

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to update the content of @ViewChildren ngWidgets after a new widget is added.

```
@Component({
    selector:'grid',
    template :<widget *ngFor="let widget of widgets" ></widget>
});
export class grid {

    @ViewChildren(NgWidget) ngWidgets : QueryList<NgWidget>;
    public widgets=[];

    ngAfterViewInit(){
         this.ngWidgets.changes.subscribe((e)=>{
            e.last.name= 'lun';
        });
    this.widgets.push('1');

    }
}

@Component({
    selector:'widget',
    template:'div [innerHTML]="name"></div>
})
export class ngWidget{
    public name='';
}
```

I am getting the error 'Expression has changed after it was checked.', because of double detection.  Is there another way to update the name of the widget when a new widget is added?